# Net::HTTPNotFound (404) For API Call. Paste in the URL into browser and 200

Tags: ruby, httparty, wistia

While using the Wistia API, I've encountered this strange phenomena: 200 in browser, 404 from HTTParty.

Currently, I have a video module with an embed class as so:

```
module Video
  class Embed
    include ActiveModel::Model
    include HTTParty

    base_uri 'https://fast.wistia.net/oembed'
    format :json
    default_params api_password: ENV['WISTIA_PASSWORD']

    class << self
      def find(hashed_id)
        get("", query: { url: url_query("#{hashed_id}") })
      end

      private

      def url_query(hashed_id)
        "http%3A%2F%2Fhome%2Ewistia%2Ecom%2Fmedias%2F#{hashed_id}"      
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When performing a `Video::Embed.find(@video.hashed_id)` the code that is output appears as so in the log:

```
HTTP GET (59.97ms)   https://fast.wistia.net:443/oembed?api_password=not_getting_my_password&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome%2Ewistia%2Ecom%2Fmedias%2Fth3-3Xamp13
Response status   Net::HTTPNotFound (404)
Response body
```

But, if I paste in my url, I can see the JSON load inside of the browser (200).

The password is correct (tested), the hashed_id is correct (tested), and the URL was tested by pasting in the url into the browser.

I have a feeling its a cross-origin issue, but even then I'm not sure how to solve that one.

**Update**: Performing a curl returns the JSON just like the browser.

Comment: LOoks like there is an F missing before home in url in the log statement, `http://` should become `http%3A%2F%2Fhome` but the second F is missing.

Comment: The second F is there. Accidental deletion as I was editing the subdomain.

Comment: Good eye though @looseseal_90. But the log was just edited by me to keep the domain safe.